# Nativescript setting selectedIndex on BottomNavigation not working on Android

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm trying to programmatically set the `selectedIndex` of my bottom-navigation.

It works on iOS - but on Android, nothing happens.

```
const rootView = Application.getRootView();
    const bottomBar = rootView.getViewById("bottomNavigation");
console.log('bottomBar', bottomBar.selectedIndex);
    bottomBar.selectedIndex = 2;
    console.log('bottomBar-changed', bottomBar.selectedIndex);
```

The `console.log` shows that the selectedIndex actually changed.

I tried `rootView.requestLayout()` to refresh the view, but that didn't help.

Any ideas?

Nativescript 8.x, BottomBar from plugin (@nativescript-community/ui-material-bottom-navigation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was a bug in 5.2.15 - updated to 5.2.17 and now it's working.